# Processing a URL recieved in REST API

Tags: python, api, flask

I have built an API in Flask that turns HTML pages through their URLS to PDF. However whenever the URL has slashes in it, the script outputs a 404.

this is the code -

```
def api(self):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route('/api/dodo/<filename>/<url>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

    def convert(url, filename):
        content = request.json
        outfile = pdfkit.from_url(str(url), filename)
        return jsonify({"url":url, 'filename': filename})

    app.run(debug=True)
```

if the request is `localhost/api/dodo/filename/google.com`
I do get the output file. But if I send this request

```
http://localhost/api/dodo/filename/https://dev.bizlem.io:8082/scorpio1/GALBRAITH'S_FUEL_27K-55K_ETA_CENTRAL_MED_LIST_-_14TH_JANUARY_2019_1.html
```

I get 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, this is happening because the url in the latter case actually maps to a different endpoint. Notice that the slashes added in the url change the meaning.

A better approach is to urlencode `filename` and `url` parameters, and pass them as GET parameters (From what I see, /api/dodo is your REST API endpoint and `filename`, `url` are parameters).

The code should look somewhat like this:

```
def api():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/api/dodo', methods=['GET'])
    def convert():
        url = request.args.get('url')
        filename = request.args.get('filename')
        outfile = pdfkit.from_url(url, filename)

        return jsonify({"url":url, 'filename': filename})

    app.run(debug=True)
```

The url to access the resource would then be:

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/dodo?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.bizlem.io%3A8082%2Fscorpio1%2FGALBRAITH%27S_FUEL_27K-55K_ETA_CENTRAL_MED_LIST_-_14TH_JANUARY_2019_1.html&filename=okay`

Comment: I did try URL encoding the values like so, but to no effect. I still get the same error. `outfile = pdfkit.from_url(str.encode(url), str.encode(filename))` Do you mean that I should encode the requests that I am sending towards my API?

Comment: That was not what I meant. When you're making a request, send `filename` and `url` as GET parameters, as in, `http://localhost/api/dodo?filename=<filename>&url=<url>` and access them using `request.args.get('filename')` and `request.args.get('url')`. Note that <filename> and <url> have to be urlencoded.

Comment: I tried that, It still 404's on me. Even a simple GET request wouldn't work. I tried the format you mentioned. No luck

Comment: The code I just added seems to work fine, try it and let me know if it does.

Comment: You're a life saver, this worked flawlessly, thank you so much